# Geoserver Black Squares in ImageMosaic

Tags: raster, geoserver, image-mosaic, ecw

I have encountered a new issue that only appears on one of many ImageMosiac layers on my Geoserver (2.7.3).

[image: ImageMosaic Black Sqaure]

It appears that Geoserver is skipping 2 tiles in the ImageMosaic that it generated. It is the same whether viewed via WMS or as a web map via Layer Preview.

The same layer appears correct without the black squares when dragged locally into ArcGis 10.3. The files are in ECW format.

Any ideas what might cause this? I've rebuilt the layer and replaced the files but issue persists.

UPDATE: 
I've enabled geotools developer logging as suggested and I believe this is the error. I haven't been able to work out the root cause however. The issue only affects this layer - not any others on this server.

```
2018-05-29 07:09:44,370 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock:file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/ECW.shp by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader
2018-05-29 07:09:44,370 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Shapefile Reader has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-05-29 07:09:44,370 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/ECW.dbf by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.IndexedDbaseFileReader
2018-05-29 07:09:44,370 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Dbase File Reader has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-05-29 07:09:44,370 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/ECW.shx by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile
2018-05-29 07:09:44,370 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-05-29 07:09:44,370 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Producing the final mosaic, step 1, loop through granule collectors
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Using collector with filter:Filter.INCLUDE
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CV_083.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CU_084.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CT_082.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CU_081.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CU_085.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CV_082.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CT_084.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CT_085.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,371 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CU_083.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,372 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/imagery/firemaps/south-melbourne-1930s/ECW/South_Melbourne_193_CT_081.ecw
2018-05-29 07:09:44,372 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Producing the final mosaic, step 2, final mosaicking
2018-05-29 07:09:44,372 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Loaded bbox ReferencedEnvelope[318433.6941292357 : 320542.257464717, 5810814.247994417 : 5812466.928877863] while crop bbox ReferencedEnvelope[318433.6941292357 : 320542.257464717, 5810814.247994417 : 5812466.928877863]
2018-05-29 07:09:44,373 WARN [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Could not reduce the grid geometry inside the valid area bounds: ReferencedEnvelope[102.0 : 192.0, -90.0 : 90.0]
Grid geometry isGridGeometry2D[GridEnvelope2D[127..1413, 183..1191], PARAM_MT["Affine",
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3],
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3],
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 1.6400000000000001],
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 318225.16550999996],
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -1.6400000000000001],
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 5812766.704229999]]]
2018-05-29 07:09:44,374 WARN [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Could not reduce the grid geometry inside the valid area bounds: ReferencedEnvelope[102.0 : 192.0, -90.0 : 90.0]
Grid geometry isGridGeometry2D[GridEnvelope2D[127..1413, 183..1191], 
PARAM_MT["Affine",
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3],
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3],
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 1.6400000000000001],
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 318225.16550999996],
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -1.6400000000000001],
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 5812766.704229999]]]
2018-05-29 07:09:44,374 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY)
2018-05-29 07:09:44,374 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY): found implementation BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.
2018-05-29 07:09:44,375 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Reprojecting to crs PROJCS["GDA94 / MGA zone 55",
  GEOGCS["GDA94",
DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994",
```

Comment: You may get some information by turning the logging level into GeoTools Developer. It will write much log so turn the level back once you have collected some data about your issue.

Comment: That version of GeoServer is way old and has not been supported for a long time. I suggest you try out with 2.13.0 first.

Comment: OK i've enabled logging but not sure how to interpret this. I would love to upgrade the server however this was the only version I could get to work with ECW files which was a requirement at the time.